Dual-Boot Performance Profile Persisting Across Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 11
I have encountered a problem using my dual-boot laptop Thunderobot Zero (i9-13900, nvidia rtx gpu), which runs both Ubuntu 24.04 and Windows 11. The laptop came with Windows 11 pre-installed, along with the manufacturer's Control Center software, which is essential for managing performance and energy efficiency profiles.
Here's the crux of the problem: whenever I set the laptop to "Energy Saving" mode in Windows 11 using the Control Center, I subsequently encounter difficulties upon booting into Ubuntu. The fans operate quieter and the system performance seems diminished. Occasionally, the laptop shuts down due to overheating. Conversely, if I switch the performance profile to "High Performance" in Control Center under Windows 11 before booting into Ubuntu, the fans run louder and there are no performance issues observed.
This leads me to believe that the performance profile settings may be carrying over from Windows to Ubuntu. Is it possible that these settings are influencing the hardware behavior during the Ubuntu session? If so, how can one ensure that the respective operating systems maintain separate control over the hardware settings, avoiding crossover impacts?
Your insights and guidance on how to rectify this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I am sure this exact same question was asked a few days ago, maybe not by same user. Anyway hardware level changes made in Windows can and will carry over to other OS as they are hardware level way below the start of any OS.

Things you do in Windows that affect the hardware at a low level often carry over to other OS.
What you are setting is carrying over as it must be setting the hardware this way.
Nothing in Ubuntu you can do about this unless the maker has control software that runs on Ubuntu. That is not likely.
